# extract data from rss feed in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I need to read the woeid from the xml doc below. I need to read and store the data into a string variable  so I can query the yahoo weather service.

XML returned  by query:

```
<query yahoo:count="1"
       yahoo:created="2009-12-22T08:30:31Z"
       yahoo:lang="en-US"
       yahoo:updated="2009-12-22T08:30:31Z"
       yahoo:uri="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select+woeid+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22farnborough%2C+greater+london%2Cuk%22">
−
<diagnostics>
<publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
−
<url execution-time="32">
http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q(farnborough%2C%20greater%20london%2Cuk);start=0;count=10
</url>
<user-time>33</user-time>
<service-time>32</service-time>
<build-version>4265</build-version>
</diagnostics>
−
<results>
−
<place>
<woeid>19941</woeid>
</place>
</results>
</query>
```

Can someone show me how to do this through linq?

----------EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I've just realised i linq is not supported by .net 2.0...doh

So please could some suggest an alternative way using references available with .net 2.0? -maybe repost and tag?
Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string s = doc.Descendants()
              .Where(element => element.Name == "woeid")
              .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: A question regrding this line:
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

i cannot pass it the xml document as it takes string. Can i pass it the xmldoc.ToString()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to this Linq query to get the results back from the XML document

```
XDocument feeds = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = feeds.Descendants("diagnostics")
                    .Select(f => new 
                    {
                        UserTime = f.Element("uset-time").Value,
                        ServiceTime = f.Element("service-time").Value,
                        //... etc
                    }.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a way](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/06/05/from-linq-to-xpath-and-back-again.aspx) to extract values from an xml file using Linq and xPath.

Hope this helps some.